# Creating CocoaPod, get error I can't solve about missing file (that is there)

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoapods

I am trying to create a pod (first one) for this project:

https://github.com/xeppen/GLLingoManager

I run $ pod spec lint GLLingoManager.podspec and I get an error.

```
 -> GLLingoManager (0.1.0)
- ERROR | xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
- NOTE  | xcodebuild:  GLLingoManager/Classes/GLLingoManager.m:10:9: fatal error: 'GLNetworkService.h' file not found
```

I am checking the files and all seem correct. Demo project works etc.

How can I solve this? I dont understand why it says its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SDK, I think you need to create subspec and specify search paths for each of the SDK may giving issues, for example :

```
s.subspec "Kairos" do |ss|
    ss.dependency "Kairos", "~> 2.1"
    ss.xcconfig = { "FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS" => "$(PODS_ROOT)/Heyzap"}
end
```